# return boolean value for a custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, return

I am comparing key elements in a list with dictionary keys

```
event_test = {
    "EventType": "ShipmentDueDate", 
    "Endpoint": "https://example.net"
    }

events_list = ['EventType','Endpoint']
body = "https"
```

I wrote a custom function as follows

```
def validate_input(event_keys,body): 
  count = 0 
  for list_item in events_list: 
    if list_item in event_keys:
        count+= 1
  if count != len(events_list):
      print("One/All of: 'EventType','Endpoint' parameters are missing.")
  if not "https" in body:
      print("Only https endpoints are accepted")
  return bool
```

I want to execute the other part of my code, only if the function executes without any errors. I dont understand how to specify a return value for the function and execute my code based on the return value

I am trying this : calling my function first

```
validate_response = validate_input(list(event_test.keys()),body)

if validate_response == False:
    print("error in your input")
try:
    print("execute my rest of the code")
```

Is this the right way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, I see a couple of issues

**1. There is an issue with your eval condition (you are missing an `else`)**

```
if validate_response == False:
    print("error in your input")
else:
    print("execute my rest of the code")
```

**2. Your function is not returning `True` or `False` AND the `not in` operator isn't used correctly when checking for 'https'**

```
def validate_input(event_keys,body):
    count = 0
    for list_item in events_list:
        if list_item in event_keys:
            count+= 1
    if count != len(events_list):
        print("One/All of: 'EventType','Endpoint' parameters are missing.")
        return False
    if "https" not in body:
        print("Only https endpoints are accepted")
        return False
    return True
```

**Moving on...**

I am a bit unclear as to what you're referring to as the "right way"

I'll take a stab at it and assume you are referring to reducing the complexity and/or lines of code in your sample...

You may try to use the following "optimizations"

**Changing your function to use list comprehensions**

*NOTE: I did change the name of the "body" function param to "body_str" as it shadowed the body variable from the outer scope. Please avoid this as a rule of thumb*

```
def validate_input(event_keys, body_str):
    count = len([x for x in events_list if x in event_keys])
    # print count to debug
    print(f"Count is {count}")
    if count != len(events_list):
        print("One/All of: 'EventType','Endpoint' parameters are missing.")
        return False
    if "https" not in body_str:
        print("Only https endpoints are accepted")
        return False
    return True
```

*The following line essentially returns a new list of elements that match your if condition, it then uses the len operation to count the number of elements that matched the said condition*

```
count = len([x for x in events_list if x in event_keys])
```

**Changing your evaluation**

*One possibility (I would personally use this)*

```
if not validate_response:
    print("error in your input")
else:
    print("execute my rest of the code")
```

*Another possibility is to get rid of temporary variable assignment altogether - reduces readability though*

```
# validate_response = validate_input(list(event_test.keys()),body)

if not validate_input(list(event_test.keys()), body_str):
    print("error in your input")
else:
    print("execute my rest of the code")
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you never defined the value of `bool` in your code sample. `bool` is a builtin function, so `validate_input` will actually always return the function `bool`, which will cause the program not to work as intended.

A better way to implement this would be to return `False` if either of the error conditions are met, and return `True` otherwise, like so:

```
def validate_input(event_keys,body): 
  count = 0 
  for list_item in events_list: 
    if list_item in event_keys:
        count+= 1
  if count != len(events_list):
      print("One/All of: 'EventType','Endpoint' parameters are missing.")
      return False
  if not "https" in body:
      print("Only https endpoints are accepted")
      return False
  return True
```

Additionally, `validate_input` isn't actually raising any exceptions, it's simply returning `True` or `False` based on whether the function parameters are valid. There's no need for a `try-except` statement; you can simply use an `if-else` statement, like so:

```
if validate_response:
    print("execute my rest of the code")
else:
    print("error in your input")
```

With the above changes, `"error in your input"` will be printed if `validate_response` is `False`. `validate_input` will return `True` if all items found in `events_list` are also present in parameter `event_keys`, and `"https"` is in `body`.